# jquery removeClass only if all checkboxes of the same set (with same class?) are unchecked

Tags: jquery, checkbox, parent, siblings

### The problem

When a checkbox is unchecked, if other checkboxes of the same set (with same class?) are checked, the class shouldn't be removed.
Please notice there are several sets of checkboxes.

### (Partially) working fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/mirluin/3MpYw/1/

### Html code

```
<form method="get" action="#" class="taxonomy-drilldown-checkboxes">
    <div class="btn-group taxonomy-search-btn" id="terms-clipping_bu">
        <a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
            Business Units
            <span class="caret"></span>
        </a>

        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li class="term-item ">
                <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="qmt[clipping_bu][]" value="4" checked="checked" />Bu1</label>
            </li>
            <li class="term-item ">
                <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="qmt[clipping_bu][]" value="27" checked="checked" />Bu2</label>
            </li>
            <li class="term-item ">
                <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="qmt[clipping_bu][]" value="31" />Bu3</label>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="btn-group taxonomy-search-btn" id="terms-clipping_market">
        <a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
            Markets
            <span class="caret"></span>
        </a>

        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li class="term-item ">
                <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="qmt[clipping_market][]" value="34" />UK</label>
            </li>
            <li class="term-item current-term">
                <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="qmt[clipping_market][]" value="57" checked="checked" />France</label>
            </li>
            <li class="term-item current-term">
                <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="qmt[clipping_market][]" value="65" checked="checked" />Germany</label>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <p>
        <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Submit" /> <a class="taxonomy-drilldown-reset btn btn-info" href="#">Reset</a>
    </p>
</form>
```

### Javascript

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    // verify if any checkboxes are checked, if so highlight the dropdown link
    $(':checkbox:checked').each(function () {

        var $check = $(this),
        $ul = $check.parents('ul.dropdown-menu'),
        $div = $ul.siblings('a.btn.dropdown-toggle');

        if ($check.prop('checked')) {
            $div.addClass('btn-warning');
        }
    });

    // on every click on checkboxes...
    $('.taxonomy-drilldown-checkboxes input[type=checkbox] ').change(function () {

        var $check2 = $(this),
        $ul = $check2.parents('ul.dropdown-menu'),
        $div = $ul.siblings('a.btn.dropdown-toggle');

        // if adding a checkbox highlight the dropdown link 
        if ($check2.prop('checked')) {

            $div.addClass('btn-warning');

            // if removing a checkbox, remove the class
            // only if all checkboxes *of the same set* are unchecked too
        } else {

            $div.removeClass('btn-warning');
        }
    });
});
```

### CSS

Nothing fancy!

```
.btn-warning {
    background-color: #faa732;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You almost had it, you just need to check if there is any checkbox still checked when you uncheck one, instead of :

```
else {

    $div.removeClass('btn-warning');
}
```

You put

```
else if($ul.find('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length == 0){

    $div.removeClass('btn-warning');
}
```

This will find the number of checked checkboxes in the current ul, and if it's equal to 0, will remove the class. Example here : http://jsfiddle.net/3MpYw/2/